# Apply css style depending on scope variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-style

I'm trying to set a css property depending on a scope variable.

Basically, something like this :

```
 <div ng-style="background: filters.area ? #f39c12 : #424242">
```

Or maybe it should be more like :

```
<div ng-style="filters.area ? 'background:#f39c12' : 'background:#424242'">
```

or even :

```
<div ng-style="{{filters.area ? 'background:#424242' : 'background:#ff0000'}}">
```

But none of the above worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background` value would be set by ternary operator & Also use `{` & `}` instead of `{{}}` interpolation.

Basically `ng-style` directive asks for `JSON` & internally it use `element.css(JSON)`

```
<div ng-style="{'background' : filters.area ? '#424242' : '#ff0000'}">
```

Comment: I guess you meant without the first background since it already is in the ternary result.

I have something like this :
`<div class="filterContent" ng-style="{filters.area ? 'background:#f39c12' : 'background:#ff0000'}">` but it doesn't do anything, the background of the `filterContent` class stays even if I add `!important;` after both color codes

Comment: @Ellone that was my bad in copy paste..do look at my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax error in the expression inside ***ng-style*** directive. Try this way,

***HTML :***

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div id="customControl" ng-style="filterarea ? {'background': '#f39c12'} : {'background':'#424242'}"></div>
</div>
```

***javaScript : (angularjs)***

```
angular.module("myapp", []).controller("MainController", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.filterarea = false;
}]);
```

***CSS :***

```
#customControl{
    width : 100px;
    height : 100px;
    background-color : yellow;
}
```

[***jsFiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/bp3asy49/)

Comment: Thanks ! `ng-style="filters.area ? {'background': '#f39c12'} : {'background':'#424242'}">` works just fine !

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a single pair '{}'. This code can be easily fixed by using

```
<div ng-style="{filters.area ? 'background:#424242' : 'background:#ff0000'}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jpk547zp/3/
For further help with ng-style check: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

```
<div ng-app="approvalApp">
    <div ng-controller="SimpleApprovalController" >
        <div ng-style="filters.area ? {'background-color' : '#424242'} : {'background-color' : '#ff0000'}">
            test data
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```